# Read lines from a file and output each line with a line number

Tags: perl, text

I'm really new to Perl programming and I'm writing a program that opens a file and reads in each line of the file one by one. It then outputs the file with a line number at the beginning of each line.

As of right now I'm reading in the lines, but I don't know how to distinguish individual lines and output something at the beginning.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict
use warnings

my $file = 'FILENAME.txt';
open(my $txt_file, '<', $file) or die "Could not open file."

while (my $lines = <$txt_file>) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `perl -ne'printf "%04d %s", $., $_' FILENAME.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) variable holds the current line number for the last filehandle accessed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'FILENAME.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    print "$. $line";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to format this so it outputs the line number with 4 digits? e.g.. line 64 would be 0064

Comment: @toolic: The formats are explained in [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), though.